# When were the doctrine and covenants published and distributed to members of the LDS church?

Tags: church-history, lds, doctrine-and-covenants

I know that the doctrines and covenants to the LDS church are scriptures that came by revelation.

In what date range was that book of scripture written?

At what date was that book of scripture published and distributed to the majority of the church?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first revelations were written while Joseph Smith was translating the Book of Mormon, beginning about 1828. It was decided in 1831 to publish a compilation as the  "Book of Commandments", at the press that was being established in Independence, Missouri. The printing was in progress but not complete when the printing office was mobbed and destroyed in July 1833. An expanded version was printed two years later (1835) in Kirtland, Ohio. This was the first published version generally available. Subsequent editions included more revelations, until the death of Joseph Smith in 1844, although successors have added a few more sections and a couple of "Offical Declarations".

Comment: It's not just the Official Declarations.  A few sections were added after the death of Joseph Smith, see sections 135, 136 and 138.  I think those are the only ones, but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: There have been a number of republications since 1835, and most of them have re-shaped select phrases and sections within D&C. The initial 1835 mass publication was also a significant re-work of the material which had been previously published across 1828-1833. For those who are interested, there's an 1833 copy of the BoC available [on the institute for Religious Research](http://irr.org/boc1833p10gif).